# how to write a generic sort in angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, sorting

I am writing an angular.js application, and i need to do a filter-orderBy on a JSON array.
if i do it by creating a method that takes no parameters and refers to the explicit array with $scope, everything works fine:

```
...
<th class="ui th" ng-click="sortArray('name')">Name</th>
...

sortArray = (sortParam) ->
  $scope.myArray = $filter('orderBy')($scope.myArray, sortParam)
```

but if i try to generify it by having the array as a method parameter, like this:

```
...
<th class="ui th" ng-click="sortArray(myArray,'name')">Name</th>
...

sortArray = (arr,sortParam) ->
  arr = $filter('orderBy')(arr, sortParam)
```

it seems like the array is sorted in the backend, but the table that uses it for ng-repeat stays unchanged, visually. example: i have this array:

```
{ arr : 
 [
  { 'id' : 1 },
  { 'id' : 2 },
  { 'id' : 3 }
 ]
}
```

now, in the first case, if i sort with the first case, the rendering changes to match the sorted array. but in the second case, the rendering will not change (it will still show as 1 - 2 - 3), but if i have it print the id of the first cell (which renders '1') it will say '3' (the top of the array after sorting. hope it makes sense.

the reason i need it is to open a modal with the content of the row clicked. for that, i put an ng-click in the ng-repeat tag, with the index:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in arr | filter:filter" ng-click="loadModal($index)">
```

that way, even if the array is reordered, the value of loadModal($index) does not change, in will open with the correct row.

so, after this long explanation - how do i write a generic method that can take and order different array (code reuse) but affects the rendering too? or, is this the right way to even do so? i don't have an ID for the entries of the array, and there is nothing natural i can cling to, to identify the row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to write a `generic method`!

Use the `orderBy` filter with `ng-repeat` in your view like

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
```

And on `ng-click` set the `predicate` value like

```
<th class="ui th" ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse= !reverse">Name</th>
```

When you click `Name` the `predicate` will pass the value to `orderBy` filter and your view adjust the latest change automatically,  `reverse= !reverse` used for toggle your sort.

Check the angularjs <kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/g7LHydZ0gDCmFup1TSp2?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: you are right at that, and i forgot some more info: the problem with the solution in the demo (which i did try before) is this: when the user click on an entry in the table, i open a modal with the content of that row. the way i found to correlate between the table and the backend array is to put an ng-click="openModal($index)" in the ng-repeat tag, so the initial rendering sets the value of ng-click for each row, which does not change when i reorder the array. i edited the question above.

Comment: `openModal($index)` this is not gonna help you ! instead `$index` use your array unique property something like `Id` because `$index` used for `ng-repeat` item indexing.

Comment: it is true and that is the reason i use it, as $index might change with reorder but openModal(($index) will be created once on page load, will correspond to the array's initial indexes and will not change on reorder.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding ! Initially when you click row two `$index` return 1, after reordering if you click again on row two `$index` will return 1 but the content of the row changed. In your case always `$index` will be same but the content of the row will be changed. So if you want to get row content use some unique id from your array instead `$index`